# "I tend to favour the opinion that when young men do well it is because of their parents …" — Why is this an it-cleft construction?

Tags: cleft-constructions

the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, page 1493, example 35i:
**(1)** *I tend to favour the opinion that when young men do well it is because of their parents, and when they do badly it is because of themselves*.

The book says this example belongs to the it-cleft construction.

As far as I know, the structure of an it-cleft sentence is:
*it's + antecedent + relative clause beginning with "that" or "who"*.
So I can't find the it-cleft construction in (1).
Could you explain to me please where it is and why it can be called so here?

Comment: Perhaps this could be considered a __truncated *it*-cleft__ as discussed on p. 1417. "When they do badly it is because of themselves [that they do badly]."

Comment: *[**An it-cleft**](https://www.thoughtco.com/it-cleft-sentence-term-1691086) begins with **nonreferential it** (the "**cleft pronoun**"), which is typically followed by a copula (i.e., a form of the verb be), a noun phrase, and a relative clause.* The cited example has a "dummy" ***it*** (nonreferential) and copula *(**is**)* as specified, and there's nothing in that definition *requiring* "who", "that", or whatever. They're just *typically* present in many examples.

Comment: @nschneid I think you could write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this could be considered a **truncated it-cleft** as discussed on p. 1417. "When they do badly it is because of themselves [that they do badly]." The relative clause is not explicit but its meaning can be inferred from context.

Answer (score -1):

> I tend to favour the opinion that when young men do well it is because of their parents, and when they do badly it is because of themselves.

Let's extract the opinion and reverse the order:

**It is because of their parents when young men do well, and it is because of themselves when they do badly.**

They're not requiring  **it** to precede the clause for which it is a semantic proxy; the moving of the independent clause introduced by **it** to initial position in the sentence is a frequent feature of such constructions, but not an essential characteristic.

And they're allowing a clause introduced by **when**:

> "We regret ***when** our students require disciplining*" said the headmaster, gripping an ancient mace.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand how your post answers the original question. Maybe you want to say that "_It is because of their parents when young men do well, and it is because of themselves when they do badly_" is an it-cleft sentence to you?

Comment: Please re-read the sentence that begins "They're [i.e. CGEL] not requiring..."

Comment: Ok. The only conclusion I can draw from what you wrote is that you confuse extraposition with it-cleft construction.

Comment: non-cleft version: They do well because of their parents. cleft-version: It is because of their parents they do well.

Comment: "It is because of their parents (that, when) they do well."   Cleft-version with the clauses reversed: When they do well it is because of their parents.

Comment: "_It is because of their parents when they do well_." - that's extraposition, that's not an it-cleft sentence.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence "It was because she was so lonely all the time that she decided to move out."

Comment: You do not accept *when they do well* as a content-clause?

Comment: "_It is because of their parents **when** they do well_." – extraposition. "_It is because of their parents **that** they do well_." – an it-cleft sentence.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause  at  "I like (it) when she comes to visit." And see in my answer where I say "They're allowing a clause introduced by **when**".